Как сделать заглавными последнюю букву каждого слова в строке
Есть вопрос по задаче.
Условие:

Дана строка. Сделайте заглавной последнюю букву каждого слова в этой строке.

Пробовал написать код на основе кода который делает заглавной вторую букву каждого слова в строке.


my_string = input("Введите строку: ").split()
  counter = 1
  new_list = []
  for i in my_string:
      if counter == my_string[-1]:
          i = i.capitalize()
      new_list.append(i)
      counter += 1
  print(*new_list)

Но он не делает последнюю букву заглавной.

Введите строку: python language


python language

Подскажите в чём ошибка.

if counter == my_string[-1]: Здесь явно что-то не то

print(input()[::-1].title()[::-1])

@StanislavVolodarskiy опубликуйте как ответ, хороший пример!)

@StanislavVolodarskiy - это решение переведет все остальные буквы в нижний регистр. а по тексту задания не понятно, дозволено ли это.

Если вы нашли работоспособный алгоритм, "который делает заглавной вторую букву каждого слова в строке", то вам нужно добавить к каждому слову по одной букве и записать строку наоборот, применить готовый алгоритм, записать результат наоборот и убрать по букве в конце каждого слова. Готово!

Можно написать функцию, которая будет разбивать строку на список слов и для каждого из них отделять последний символ i[:-1], и присоединять его уже в верхнем регистре i[:-1].upper():
def upper_last_symb(my_string: str) -> list:
    return [i[:-1] +  i[-1].upper() for i in  my_string.split()]


my_string = input("Введите строку: ")
list_w_words = upper_last_symb(my_string)
for word in list_w_words:
    print(word)

Ввод:
стол ручка тетрадь

Вывод:
стоЛ
ручкА
тетрадЬ



Сделайте заглавной последнюю букву каждого слова в этой строке

Давайте декомпозируем задачу.

сделайте заглавной
последнюю букву
каждого
слова
в этой строке

Реализовывать это всё нужно в обратном порядке:

"в этой строке" - вводим строку через input
"слова" - введённую строку нужно разбить на слова с помощью функции split
"каждого" - полученные отдельные слова нужно перебрать с помощью цикла
"последнюю букву" - вырезаем из слова два куска с помощью срезов: до последней буквы и сама последняя буква
"сделайте заглавной" - полученную ранее последнюю букву делаем заглавной с помощью функции upper
Ну и последний шаг - нужно собрать всё обратно:


слепить обратно слова, теперь уже с заглавной последней буквой
слепить обратно предложения (или это тут не надо? из задания непонятно, возможно достаточно вернуть список слов)
вернуть полученный результат

Хорошо бы ещё посмотреть примеры к этой задаче, потому что слова могут быть разделены пробелами, и тогда split будет достаточно. А могут быть разделены другими знаками препинания, и тогда будет лучше использовать регулярные выражения для поиска слов.
Ну а теперь сравните план выше со своим кодом. Мягко говоря, многое у вас не так.
P.S. Увидел пример. У вас всё просто, split с дефолтными аргументами достаточно.
P.P.S. Ладно, раз всё-равно уже код все пишут, то вот однострочник:
print(' '.join(f'{s[:-1]}{s[-1].upper()}' for s in input().split()))

